# Difficulties with getting maximum power of 3 of a number

Tags: python

I'm doing a method which calculates amount of greenbucks which are needed to pay the amount of money. The denominations of banknotes are powers of 3. `(1, 3, 9, 27, 81...)`. It works pretty well, but sometimes it shows `pow(3, 4)` on a `69` number (hehe) which is `81` (it's higher than `64`).

I probably messed up with loops. :/

The results:

`ile(69)`

```
5
0 x 81 = 0
2 x 27 = 54
1 x 9 = 9
2 x 3 = 6
0 x 1 = 0
```

`ile(120)`

```
4
1 x 81 = 81
1 x 27 = 27
1 x 9 = 9
1 x 3 = 3
0 x 1 = 0
```

`ile(29)`

```
3
1 x 27 = 27
0 x 9 = 0
0 x 3 = 0
2 x 1 = 2
```

`ile(64)`

```
4
2 x 27 = 54
1 x 9 = 9
0 x 3 = 0
1 x 1 = 1
```

The expected output of `ile(69)` is:

```
5
2 x 27 = 54
1 x 9 = 9
2 x 3 = 6
0 x 1 = 0
```

The results are perfectly good (4, 3, 4) but the analyzing doesn't work. 
It shows (0 x 81) which is true, but why is it there? Help.

My code:

```
def ile(number):
    denominations = []

    temp = number
    currentPower = 0

    while True:
        nextPower = int(pow(3, currentPower))

        temp -= nextPower
        currentPower += 1

        denominations.append(nextPower)

        if ((temp - nextPower) < 0):
            break

    temp = number

    greenbacks = []

    for denomination in reversed(denominations):
        div = int(temp / denomination)

        greenbacks.append(div)

        temp %= denomination

    amount = 0
    for greenback in greenbacks:
        amount += greenback

    print(amount)

    index = len(denominations) - 1
    for greenback in greenbacks:
        denomination = denominations[index]
        gamount = greenback * denomination;
        print(str(greenback) + " x " + str(denomination) + " = " + str(gamount))

        index -= 1

ile(69)
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @SandeepLade edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
current |   next    |   temp -= nextPower   |   (temp - nextPower)<0
________|___________|_______________________|_______________________________
    0   |   1       |       68              |   67 < 0 ==> False
    1   |   3       |       65              |   63 < 0 ==> False
    2   |   9       |       56              |   47 < 0 ==> False
    3   |   27      |       29              |   2 < 0 ==> False
    4   |   81      |       -52             |   True
        |           |                       |
```

You are subtracting nextPower from temp only once which is not true for all cases. As you can see from the table, on doing a dry run on `ile(69)` we are going upto 4th power(=81). The correct thing is when power of 3 is 3 (=27), 27 must be subtracted twice from 56 instead of once. Since you are subtracting, the condition is not evaluating to `True` and hence not breaking.

A better way to evaluate the highest power using log to the base 3.

If N is the number whose ile() is to be calculated,
then, `highest power = int(log3(N)) //we take the floor value`

The modified code:

```
        import math
        def ile(number):
            temp = number

            """while True:
                nextPower = int(pow(3, currentPower))

                temp -= nextPower
                currentPower += 1

                denominations.append(nextPower)

                if (temp - nextPower) < 0:
                    break
            """
            highest_pow = int(math.log10(temp)/math.log10(3))
            denominations = [int(pow(3,i)) for i in range(highest_pow+1)]
            temp = number

            greenbacks = []

            for denomination in reversed(denominations):
                div = int(temp / denomination)

                greenbacks.append(div)

                temp %= denomination

            amount = 0
            for greenback in greenbacks:
                amount += greenback

            print(amount)


            """
                using index and then decrementing is not the best way. 
                There exists a better,more pythonic way to do the same
                The zip function takes n lists and returns tuples of corresponding elements
                e.g:
                    a = [1,2,3]
                    b = [4,5,6]
                    c = [8,9,0]
                    for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):
                        print(x,y,z)

                    gives   1 4 8
                            2 5 9
                            3 6 0

                Here, we reverse the denominations list zip it with greenbacks 
                and obtain tuples of values from both lists
                at corresponding indices. Your way is correct but this is more pythonic.
            """
            #index = len(denominations) - 1
            for greenback,denomination in zip(greenbacks,reversed(denominations)):
                gamount = greenback * denomination;
                print(str(greenback) + " x " + str(denomination) + " = " + str(gamount))

                #index -= 1

        ile(120)
```

Hope this helps. Please comment if you need further clarifications.

Comment: Thank you so much! Python is not really my language type, I prefer Java or C# better, but I need to do some work for someone, one more time - thank you, really useful tips!

Answer (score 1):

In determining the highest power needed, you assume that each lower power will be used once (`temp -= nextPower`), which is not always the case, so you may go one power too high.